# Search, select and show a row in a DataGridView

Tags: datagridview

i want to search a color(RAL) or storage location(Lagerort) in my DataGridView, select and show the found item.
with row.select the found item get selected, but i have to scroll down in the DataGridView manually. How can show the selected row automatically?
Thanks!

```
        string sucheRAL = txt_in_RAL.Text;
        string sucheLagerort = txt_in_Lagerort.Text;
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        try
        {
            
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells["RAL"].Value == null) continue;
                {
                    row.Selected = false;
                    if (row.Cells["RAL"].Value.ToString().Equals(sucheRAL))
                    {
                        row.Selected = true;
                        row.Visible = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
                if (row.Cells["Lagerort"].Value == null) continue;
                {
                    row.Selected = false;
                    if (row.Cells["Lagerort"].Value.ToString().Equals(sucheLagerort))
                    {
                        row.Selected = true;
                        row.Visible = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;`

Answer (score 0):

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
```

That´s the piece of code what i need ;)